# Drop Down select not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down, which works in almost all browsers.

```
<select id="productField" onchange="productField_onChange();" />
```

In FireFox it looks something like this :-

[image]

My Drop Down Code

```
<select id="productField" runat="server">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Select Product</option>
</select>
```

But in IE 11 it looks like :-

[image]

Is there any way to fix this through jquery/javascript.

Comment: please post full dropdown code...

Comment: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11">

Comment: Lol :D. Don't fear... it is a default behavior of IE 11.

Comment: @Sankar - Is there any work around.

Comment: Its new design in IE it will open on top and bottom both place not just down ..

Comment: have you got 2 selects with same id?

Comment: @user3106445 :- you can add more option to your drop down and check you will undarstand what i want to say check Sanker Raj Comment as well ..

Comment: @user3106445 Yes. 2 ways, 1. Ask microsoft to change their browser behavior. 2. Create your own dropdown using HTML/JS/CSS. Simple

Comment: I think what everyone is trying to say is that the drop-down is not broken in IE 11, you only have 1 option, so it is showing you that 1 option ( IE 11 renders its drop down in the way you are seeing ), if you add another option, it will become more clear the way that IE 11 renders.